# cant added foreign key on new table Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have two tables like User and Roles . i want to added foreign Roles_id on Table Users .

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('NIK',16);
        $table->string('nama');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('roles_id')->default(1);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
}
```

and my roles table

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('roles');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

iam not catching the miss code , i using **unsignedBigInteger** , ann still error . 
i am using **-> nullable** . but didnt work . can somone find this error ?

edit . this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_roles_id_foreign` foreign key (`roles_id`) references `roles` (`id`))

Comment: Does the roles migration run before the users table migration?

Comment: i create the users tables first. now i have 2 table .users and roles . i want to make this foreign . its wrong step ?

Comment: There must be roles table already created if you want to create role_id as foreign in the users table. What you can do is change the migration file timestamp of role ahead of the users migration file timestamp.

Comment: ok look my step . i create users table (without FK on roles) , now i create roles table .(i have 2 table now without FK) .now i added foreign like on thread . i run php artisan migrate . and showing "Nothing to Migrate"

Comment: if i run migrate:fresh its error like on this thread

Comment: What if you create another migration file to alter the users table and add the foreign key ?
I don't understand about the thread you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

First, create the roles table:

```
 public function up(){
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('roles');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then create a users table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('NIK',16);
        $table->string('nama');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('roles_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

For drop the foreign key:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('users_roles_id_foreign');
    $table->dropColumn('roles_id');
});
```

Comment: ok its the solution , but how if its this project is ready but want to add this FK like this , should i need too delete this Users table and add the line FK again ?

Comment: @Adhik Mulat  I have updated my code for remove foreign key using migration. Now check